# what's wrong with my code to appear database?

Tags: php, database, codeigniter-3

help me please, my db is dbindosat and table is formpengajuan

my controller

```
    <?php 


class Crud extends CI_Controller{

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();      
        $this->load->model('m_data');
        $this->load->helper('url');

    }

    function index(){
        $data['filedata'] = $this->m_data->tampil_data()->result();
        $this->load->view('viewdata',$data);
    }
...
```

my model

```
    <?php 

class M_data extends CI_Model{
    function tampil_data(){
        return $this->db->get('formpengajuan');

    }

    function input_data($data,$table){
        $this->db->insert($table,$data);
    }
    }
```

my view (viewdata)

```
<?php 
foreach($filedata as $data){ 
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $data-> kode; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $data-> instansi; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $data-> alamatinstansi; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $data-> judulkegiatan; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $data-> jeniskegiatan; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $data-> dana; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $data-> tanggalacara; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $data-> kontak; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $data-> email; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

but messege
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: filedata

Filename: views/viewdata.php

and 
Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: views/viewdata.php

the database does not appear, please help.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to change this line of code in your controller:

```
 function index(){
    $data['filedata'] = $this->m_data->tampil_data();
    $this->load->view('viewdata',$data);
}
```

and this in your model code:

```
   function tampil_data(){
       return $this->db->get('formpengajuan')->result();
   }
```

and if you are not auto loading your database then load it in your controllers by adding this lines

```
 function __construct(){  
    parent::__construct(); 
    $this->load->database();
 }
```

Let me know if these changes did help you to solve your problem.